# 重複を除去する python リスト内包表記の書き方

Tags: python

あるquery_setを取得して、
hogeカラムに重複の値があるので下記のように
重複を消したいと考えています。
これをリスト内包表記で書きたいのですが、どのように書けばよいでしょうか。

```
want_list = []
pass_hoge_list = []
for i in list(query_set):
  if not i.get(hoge) in pass_hoge_list:
    pass_hoge_list.append(i.get(‘hoge’))
    want_list.append(i)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
{i.get("hoge"): i for i in query_set}.values()
```

こういうことでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
これで実現できました。